# R: Ploting Moran I plot in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

Helo I would like to ask how to convert clasic R `plot` in `ggplot` so it looks nicer,
in my case I would like to plot MORAN I plot in ggplot.

example:

```
library(spdep)

data(afcon, package="spData")
moran.plot(afcon$totcon, nb2listw(paper.nb))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not an immediate operation. You can look at the code of `moran.plot` to find out all the operations needed to yield the moran plot. I've piled them up here (if you run the code below, you end up with the same plot) :

```
library(spdep)
data(afcon, package="spData")

x <- afcon$totcon
listw <- nb2listw(paper.nb)
wx <- lag.listw(listw, x, zero.policy = NULL)
xwx.lm <- lm(wx ~ x)
infl.xwx <- influence.measures(xwx.lm)
is.inf <- which(apply(infl.xwx$is.inf, 1, any))

labels <- as.character(attr(listw, "region.id"))
xlab <- "afcon$totcon"
ylab <-  paste("spatially lagged", xlab)

plot(x, wx, xlab=xlab, ylab=ylab)
abline(xwx.lm)
abline(h = mean(wx), lty = 2)
abline(v = mean(x), lty = 2)
points(x[is.inf], wx[is.inf], pch = 9, cex = 1.2)
text(x[is.inf], wx[is.inf], labels = labels[is.inf], 
     pos = 2, cex = 0.7)
```

So I'd suggest to split those operations into two steps : preparing the data then plotting it. The first function would be something of the form

```
library(dplyr)

prepare_data <- function(data, x, listw){
  # prepare a dataframe with variables x and wx, from the x and listw arguments
  # this dataframe will be the base data for the ggplot() call
  plot_data <- data %>% 
    mutate(
      x = !!enquo(x),
      wx = lag.listw(listw, x, zero.policy = NULL),
      label = as.character(attr(listw, "region.id"))
    ) %>% 
    select(x, wx, label)

  # Prepare other needed objects that don't fit into a dataframe
  xwx.lm <- lm(plot_data$wx ~ plot_data$x)
  infl.xwx <- influence.measures(xwx.lm)

  # add non variables objects as attributes
  attr(plot_data, which = "is.inf") <- which(apply(infl.xwx$is.inf, 1, any))
  attr(plot_data, which = 'xwx.lm') <- xwx.lm

  return(plot_data)
}

moran_plot_data <- prepare_data(afcon, totcon, nb2listw(paper.nb))
```

This gives you all the needed object for the plot : `x`, `wx` and `label` variables, `is.inf` and `xwx.lm` objects as attributes. Then you can build a ggplot with this objects. You'll need to use the following ggplot2 functions (the code below is minimal, you'll have to add labels, styling and stuff) :

```
library(ggplot2)

inf_data <- moran_plot_data[attr(moran_plot_data, "is.inf"), ]

ggplot() + 
    geom_point(data = plot_data, mapping = aes(x, y)) + # equivalent of plot(x, wx, xlab=xlab, ylab=ylab)
    geom_abline("wxw.lm coefficients used here") +  
    geom_hline("mean(wx) used here") +
    geom_vline("mean(x) used here") +
    geom_point(data = inf_data, mapping = aes(x, y)) + 
    geom_text(data = inf_data, mapping = aes(x, y, label) +
    labs(x = "x variable", y = "Spatially lagged x variable") +
    theme("use this function to customise appearence")
```

Feel free to have an extensive look at [the ggplot2 guide](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/index.html) to help you with these functions.

Comment: If you can't manage to build the plot from my answer, I've made it entirely [here](https://gitlab.com/roamdam/dataviz/tree/master#the-moran-plot) for you